# Есть ли эквивалент для extern char *__progname в Windows?

Tags: windows, c, c++

Во многих *nix в `libc` определена глобальная переменная

```
 extern char *__progname;
```

которая после запуска программы инициализируется коротким именем запущенного загрузочного модуля.

Например:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ cat pname.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  extern char *__progname;

  return puts(__progname) == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ gcc pname.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ cp a.out /tmp/p-name
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ /tmp/p-name 
p-name
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ ./a.out 
a.out
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$
```

в Линуксе.

А есть ли аналог `__progname` для windows?

--

Или, несколько изменяя вопрос -- как в windows получить имя исполняемой программы вне области видимости аргументов `main (int argc, char *argv[])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настолько я понимаю, нужно пользоваться WinAPI-шной [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx).

Канонический код:

```
#include <Windows.h>
// надо слинковаться с Kernel32.lib
// для Visual Studio это делается в свойствах проекта или с помощью
//#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")
// в каком-нибудь .cpp-файле

TCHAR exeName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, exeName, MAX_PATH);
```

т. к. по стандарту полный путь к файлу не может быть длиннее, чем `MAX_PATH` (это около 260 что ли).

С контролем ошибок и учётом того, что путь может быть и длиннее `MAX_PATH` (и при этом начинаться с префикса `\\?\`):

```
DWORD size = MAX_PATH; // начальное значение
TCHAR* path = malloc(size * sizeof(TCHAR));

DWORD result;
while ((result = GetModuleFileName(NULL, exeName, MAX_PATH)) == size) // не хватает?
    path = realloc((size *= 2) * sizeof(TCHAR)); // увеличиваем вдвое

if (result == 0) // обработать ошибку
{
    free(path);
    return NULL;
}

return path;
```

Comment: @VladD, спасибо.

Вот так 


    #ifdef WIN32
    
    char *__progname;
    
    void
    set_progname ()
    {
      static char pname[10240];
      if (!__progname) {
        GetModuleFileName(0, pname, sizeof(pname) - 1);
        char *p = strrchr(pname, '\\');
        __progname = strdup(p + 1);
      }
    }
    #endif
    

в MinGW тоже вполне работает.

И где же Вы эту GetModuleFileName отыскали?

Comment: @avp: Отыскал в собственной памяти. Мне приходилось сталкиваться со старыми версиями MSVC, нужные знания вытребовал у старших товарищей.

---
Обратите внимание, для UNICODE-таргета это не скомпилируется, т. к. там `GetModuleFileName` за`#define`-или как `GetModuleFileNameW` (который, в свою очередь, требует `wchar_t[]`).

---
Неужели ваш занесло в мир, построенный Биллом?

Comment: Пока сам не знаю. 

Решил немного модифицировать одну свою программульку, да и задумался о переносимости. 

Но, раз уж там опять такие сложности -- наверное не буду.